# Matlab classes in a array

Tags: matlab

I've a issue with matlab constructors when I try to instantiate an array of classes.

I get the following error:

```
??? The following error occurred converting from volta to double:
Error using ==> double
Conversion to double from volta is not possible.

Error in ==> circuito>circuito.iniciarNovaVolta at 37
            Circuito.Voltas(Circuito.Nvoltas) = Volta(Nmaxpiloto);

Error in ==> testes at 99
c1.iniciarNovaVolta(10);
```

And my code is:

```
function iniciarNovaVolta(Circuito, Nmaxpiloto)
            Circuito.Voltas(Circuito.Nvoltas) = Volta(Nmaxpiloto);
            Circuito.Nvoltas = Circuito.Nvoltas + 1;
end
```

The contructor at Volta class is:

```
function Volta=volta(Nmaxpiloto)            
    if(nargin>0)    
        %Volta.Melhortempovolta=Melhortempovolta;  
              Volta.Nmaxpiloto=Nmaxpiloto;                               
           end        
end
```

I had this issue more than once, but the types looks right. Could you tell me what I can't see ?

```
function Volta=volta(Nmaxpiloto) 
if(nargin>0)
```

Comment: Can you show more code?  It would be nice to see the call to the function as well as the function you are trying to call.

Answer (score 1):

Check your types. I'm guessing that `Volta(Nmaxpiloto)` is of type double and `Circuito.Voltas(Circuito.Nvoltas)` is of type volta.  This can't be done.  Sounds like you are mixing a lot of OOP with MATLAB, which is not to say that you can't. You might want to look at this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-47534.html#bqt_gwr to see the valid MATLAB classes.

Comment: Hi again! The contructor at Volta class is:

{function Volta=volta(Nmaxpiloto)
           if(nargin>0)
               %Volta.Melhortempovolta=Melhortempovolta;
               Volta.Nmaxpiloto=Nmaxpiloto;
             
               
           end
       end }
I had this issue more than once, but the types looks right. Could you tell me what I can't see ?
function Volta=volta(Nmaxpiloto)
            if(nargin>0)

Answer (score 0):

The contructor at Volta class is:

```
function Volta=volta(Nmaxpiloto)            
    if(nargin>0)    
        %Volta.Melhortempovolta=Melhortempovolta;  
              Volta.Nmaxpiloto=Nmaxpiloto;                               
           end        
end
```

I had this issue more than once, but the types looks right. Could you tell me what I can't see ?

```
function Volta=volta(Nmaxpiloto) 
if(nargin>0)
```